# Как выполнить SQL запрос содержащий математические действия со столбцами в Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

подскажите, как выполнить такой запрос в Yii2

```
$notes = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT * FROM note WHERE  (".time()." - modified)/weight < ".$weight." AND enabled = 1 ORDER BY `id` ASC, `order` DESC" )->queryAll();
```

Он работает, но возвращает массив, а мне надо объект модели.
Через

```
$notes->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $posts = $notes->queryAll();
```

не работает, надо что то настраивать на сервере.
В общем то вопрос в том, как такой запрос выполнить средствами

```
$models = $modelName::find()
          ->where(....)
          ->andWhere(.....)
          ->orderBy(.....)
          ->all();
```

и тд

Comment: А в чем собственно проблема сделать как в последнем примере? Пишешь в функцию `where` свое условие, которое было в raw sql.

Comment: потому что условие работает со столбцами таблицы, я нигде не нашел в документации, а все способы какие нашел, попробовал. Напиши, плиз wherу, который ищет (столбец1 * столбец2 / столбец3 ) / столбец5 > 56

Comment: `->where('(столбец1 * столбец2 / столбец3 ) / столбец5 > 56')`

Comment: так не работает, это первое что я попробовал.

Comment: Какую ошибку пишет?

Comment: Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting!
код такой  ->where('type + weight < 12')

Comment: $models = $modelName::find()
            ->where('type + weight < 12')
            ->all();

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь надо обернуть условие в класс Expression. Типа того: `->where(new Expression('type + weight < 12')`

Comment: Ошибка та же код полностью такой

Comment: $models = $modelName::find()
            ->where(new Expression('type + weight < 12'))
            //->where([$this->modelPropertyParentId => $parent_id])
            ->andWhere(['enabled' => 1])
            ->orderBy($this->modelPropertyPosition)
            ->all();

Comment: Вообще эта ошибка больше похожа на то что у тебя рекурсия переполнилась. Это не SQL ошибка то вроде.

Comment: но тот же код, записанный вот таким образом

Comment: notes = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("SELECT * FROM note WHERE  (".time()." - modified)/weight < ".$weight." AND enabled = 1 ORDER BY `id` ASC, `order` DESC" )->queryAll();

Comment: нормально исполняется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$models = Shop::find()->where("(".time()." - modified)/weight < ".$weight)
  ->andWhere(['enabled' => 1])
  ->all();

  var_dump($models);
  die();
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!